how to run multiple celery tasks synchronously in celery task?
I have to design two tasks i.e. taskA and taskB for fetching data via API calls which should be capable to run in background on daily basis with schedular but can be also trigerred individually from front end as per need. Now both tasks uses APIs from same provider which has API rate limit so i have decided to create new celery task called task_main() which will trigger taskA and taskB synchrounously to minimize concurrent connection so that global Token Bucket API Rate Limiter do not get more load.
please help me how to achieve this. I have also used celery chain and partial but while using chain and callback, my first task result automatically pass to second task which i do not prefer because both tasks's arguments are fixed and assumes single argument all time so it can be triggered individually.
Your help will be highly appreciated.
@app.task
def taskA(last_update):
    pass

@app.task
def taskB(last_update):
    pass


@app.task
def taskMain():
    task_chain = chain(taskA.s(last_update), taskB.s(last_update))
    chian_result = task_chain.delay()


You have two options there.

Refactor the tasks so they work well in a Celery Chain (where result of the previous task is passed as argument in the next task).

Use immutable signatures.


Both options have good use-cases.
